# Is EmailComposeTask Class already working?

Tags: windows-phone-7

For example here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550(VS.92).asp

```
EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();
emailComposeTask.To = "user@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Body = "Email message body";
emailComposeTask.Cc = "user2@example.com";
emailComposeTask.Subject = "Email subject";
emailComposeTask.Show();
```

I read it doesnt work yet.

Answer (score 5):

I have a real device, and an application in the marketplace - it is *definitely* working. The reason it doesn't work on an emulator is that you can't set up an email account on the emulator, and the first step of the email compose task when it is run is to prompt the user to select which email account to send the email with (if you've got more than one)

Since you can't set one up on the emulator, it kicks back and you can't send an email.

The only way to test this (for now) is to debug on an actual WP7 device, but I can 100% guarantee this is working.

One thing to note about the email tasker is that you can't programmatically add attachments...yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it works on **real devices** (not on the emulator)

Comment: any reference of that please?

Comment: No reference, but I tested it on my device and use it on an app I sell on the marketplace. It works!

Answer (score 1):

Just pasted your code into an app, deployed to a device and was presented with a choice of which of my email accounts I wanted to use for the email after which the email was prepared ready editing and sending.