# Hyperlink.Click not being executed

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone

I'm writing a Windows Phone Mango app. I have a hyperlink that contains email addresses. I want it to show a message box on tap:

```
Hyperlink href = new Hyperlink();
href.Click += (s, r) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("href clicked");
};
// add href to RichTextBox
```

When I click on the hyperlink in the emulator, nothing happens. The `click +=` line is hit in a debugger, but the `new EmailComposeTask()` line isn't.

What am I doing wrong? Is `Click` not the event I want?

**Update**: I switched `EmailComposeTask` to `MessageBox` to verify that this issue isn't related to the email compose task not running on the emulator. I've reproduced this issue on my device.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is EmailComposeTask Class already working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307653/is-emailcomposetask-class-already-working)

Comment: Nope - the same issue occurs with `MessageBox.Show()` on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works:

```
            GestureService.GetGestureListener(href); // adding this makes it work
            href.Click += (s, r) =>
            {
                 MessageBox.Show("href clicked");
                 new EmailComposeTask() { To = entireLink.Value }.Show();

            };
            href.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = entireLink.Value });
```

`GetGestureListener` creates a gesture listener if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [HyperlinkButton Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.hyperlinkbutton%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [Hyperlink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is a class used with rich text document rendering.

Comment: I am trying to make links in a RichTextBox clickable. A HyperlinkButton wouldn't flow as nicely with the other RichTextBox content (right?).

Answer (score 0):

Following code is runs on device. `text` is RichTextBox object.

```
var linkText = new Run() { Text = "Link text" };
var link = new Hyperlink();
link.Inlines.Add(linkText);
link.Click += (o, e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Link clicked");
};

var paragraph = new Paragraph();
paragraph.Inlines.Add(link);

text.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```